Error on node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/src/HubConnection.ts... this.connection.features.resend = () => {
I want to add @microsoft/signalr to angular project. But when I build project it occurs error.
X [ERROR] TS7030: Not all code paths return a value. [plugin angular-compiler]
node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/src/HubConnection.ts:271:50:
  271 │                 this.connection.features.resend = () => {
      ╵   

Version is "@microsoft/signalr": "^8.0.0",
I changed noImplicitReturns:true to false. but it not worked.
